# Rails 3 - DB seed data validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, migration, rails-migrations

I am seeding a test database in Rails 3.1 through thousands of `create` calls in the `seeds.rb` file.

A little problem arises when these calls do not pass the model validations: rails will not notify me this, and the seeding goes on correctly until the end of the file. At the end of the process I do not know which records have been created and which aren't, unless I check them one by one ...

Is there a way to get notified when records do not pass validations when using `rake db:seed` or `rake db:reset`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create validations you want in the Models and use `ModelName.create!`. This will raise an exception if the input is invalid

Check this out http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/create!

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for this. Just a note for others, I searched my seed file for `.create(` and replaced with `.create!(` and quickly found my validation issue.