# Postgres + Rails: How to validate while migrating to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I have a userMigration file which creates the rows in the table manually. This called in the initialization stage. Also, on that particular table I have validations on how the user's details should be (length, uniqueness etc).

Migration.rb

```
      Models::Persistence::User.create({:email => 'testuser@cs.com',
                                    :username => 'testuser@cs.com',
                                    :first => '',
                                    :last => 'User',
                                    :password => 'Test123!!',
                                    :bio => 'User, student',
                                    # :user_id => 3,
                                    # :photoURL => "http://link",
                                    :created_by => 1})
```

My models file for users:

```
  module Persistence
# Models persistent User data
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Songkick::OAuth2::Model::ResourceOwner
  validates :bio, length:  {maximum: 500}

  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates :email, :presence => true, :allow_nil => false
  validates_format_of :email,:with => /\A[^@\s]+@([^@\s]+\.)+[^@\s]+\z/

  validates :first, :presence => true, :allow_nil => false, length: {maximum: 100}
  validates_format_of :first, :with => /[a-zA-Z]/
```

When I change the userMigration data and put in values which do not meet the validation criteria, the rows with that data is still created. (The first name in nil in the migration file but the row is still created in the db.) Is there a way to make print out an error at this stage?

Comment: Right now, one solution I can think of is that when I try to manually create during migration, I could try validating the user.  Is this the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the bang version: `create!` - it throws an error if the record is invalid.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#when-does-validation-happen-questionmark

[Rails 3 - DB seed data validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605366/rails-3-db-seed-data-validation)